# Why does sending a message using SendGrid generate a response code of 0?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email message using SendGrid and PHP. This is my code:

```
$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "noreply@example.com");
$subject = "Password Reset";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $_REQUEST["email"]);
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "Your temporary password is " . $newPassword . ".");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$sg = new \SendGrid($MY_API_KEY);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->headers();
echo $response->body();
```

I get 0 as the response code. This doesn't make sense to me, because according to [this page](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html) there is no response code of 0. Could it be that I have not properly loaded the Sendgrid library files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating php-http-client to version 3.5.1, it now works properly. I apologize for posting this on StackOverflow, as it probably would've been more suitable on the SendGrid GitHub page.